# How to get the last dictionary element on Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

How to get last element on Swift ?

```
var test: [Int:String] = [Int:String]()
test[1] = "CCC"
test[3] = "AAA"
test[2] = "BBB"
```

I am trying to get Int 3. I try to use endIndex like this

```
let (key,value) = test.endIndex
```

and

```
print(test.endIndex)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't been very clear, but I think you're trying to get the last element of an *ordered* dictionary. Swift's native Dictionary type is unordered, so you will have to manually sort it:

`test.keys.sort().last.map({ ($0, test[$0]!) })`

In your specific case, the code above will return `Optional((3, "AAA"))` (i.e. typed `Optional<(Key, Value )>`).

Comment: Work like a charm. I really hope swift have convenience function like last(). Anyway , cheers